# File upload issues in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am using CakePHP 2.5.5 and I have problem while uploading image files, actually I'm getting error when I specified root folder path. My demo code is:

```
move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img/uploads/posts/' . time().$file['name']);
$this->request->data['Post']['image'.$i] = time().$file['name'];
```

It is giving me warning:

> Warning
>   (2):move_uploaded_file(/home/username/public_html/cakephpNewApp/app/webroot/img/uploads/posts/14321060823-nature-wallpapers.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   [APP/Controller/PostsController.php, line 47]

Can anybody, please, help me out for giving proper root folder path?

Comment: What is the full warning message you have, and secondly, does the web server have access to write to that folder?

Comment: Thank you "gabe3886"   for hint...i forgot to set folder permissions..now it's working fine..

Comment: What you added wasn't the full warning. Try adding that next time.

Comment: Ok i'll update question.

Comment: there is only issue of your server change the permission of the folder 0777  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name['tmp_name'],WWW_ROOT."/img/uploads/posts/".$filename))

Answer (score 0):

you need to give full permissions to that specific folder so, that later it can store uploded file

cd /img

sudo chmod -R 777 uploads